# Sum of a infinite number of continuous functions on a set may not be continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

I was asked to give an example of series of continuous functions whose limit is discontinuous .

I gave the following example: $f_n(x) = x^n - x^{(n-1)}$ . I thought any sequence of  continuous functions which is convergent to a discontinuous function can be made by that way a series of
continuous function whose limit is discontinuous.
Am I correct?

Can anyone give me  suggestion on this?

Comment: Yes, $\lim a_n =\sum_n b_n$ where $b_1=a_1,b_k=a_k-a_{k-1}$ fro $k \geq 2$. So any limit is an infinite sum and if $a_n$'s are continuous functions so are $b_n$'s.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! But here's the standard one:

Consider $$f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$$
where $x \in \Bbb{R}$ and $n=0,1,2,...$

Then $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}= \begin{cases}
0&x= 0\\
1+x^2 &x\neq0\\
\end{cases}
 $$